# Sporadic error occurred during Service Master Key decryption with linked server

Tags: sql-server

I have a server (SERVER A) that is giving an error of `error occurred during Service Master Key decryption` on occasion when the query references a table on a different server. About 9 out of 10 times the query runs fine, but then it will give the error. It doesn't matter which linked server it is querying, or which database, it will still randomly fail and give the error. I have followed steps in other threads suggesting

```
ALTER SERVICE MASTER KEY REGENERATE
```

but that did not help. I also looked for the registry value Entropy and it exists. I have also dropped and re-added the linked server objects, but that did not help either. It is running SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition. Would greatly appreciate a fix.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28542537/an-error-occurred-during-service-master-key-decryption  Check out this post.  It suggested that a windows patch is the culprit.  I would research and try in a lower environment.  Good Luck!

Comment: I should have mentioned that I looked at that as well and we don't have that security update installed, so that appears to not be the culprit. Thanks, though.